# CocoaPods error with Card.io

Tags: ios, cocoapods, card.io

I'm trying to install Card.io (5.2.2) with cocoaPods on Xcode (7.1). But when i run my project the compilator shows me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOUtilities", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.CardIOUtilities in CheckoutTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOPaymentViewController", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.CardIOPaymentViewController in CheckoutTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

My Podfile contains:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '8.1'

# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift

use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
       pod 'Mobile-Buy-SDK'
       pod 'HanekeSwift'
       pod 'Parse'
       pod 'CardIO'
end
```

i just typed pod install, and launched the `.xcworkspace` it created.

I think it has something to do with the static libraries inside card.io, but i can't get this to work. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: In your build settings, what is 'Other linker flags' and 'Header search paths'  set to?

Comment: I tried to set Other linker flags to -lc++, and Header search path is "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/CardIO" + "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" + $(inherited)

Comment: ok, try adding $(inherited) to both your 'other linker flags' and 'header search paths' settings.

Comment: Yeah ! Other linker flags = ${inherited} did the trick. If you post this as an answer i'll mark it as correct

Comment: I too have problems with this... but I do not understand why setting `OTHER_LDFLAGS ` to `$(inherited)` would help, Cocoapods already sets that value and the pod speciic stuff in the `Pods-MYAPP.debug.xcconfig` (and corresponding .release.xcconfig) files.

Comment: Am I missing that I need to link to any Apple framwork? MobileCoreServices? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `$(inherited)` to your 'Other linker flags' build setting.