# Error with Card.io using Xcode 8.2 and Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift2, xcode8.2

I'm trying to run my project on my device (iPhone 7 Plus: I have already copied my firmware DiskImage to this Xcode folder) with Card.io installed using cocoaPods on Xcode (8.2) with Swift 2.3.

But the compilator shows me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOPaymentViewController", referenced from:
type metadata accessor for __ObjC.CardIOPaymentViewController in CheckoutViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOUtilities", referenced from:
type metadata accessor for __ObjC.CardIOUtilities in CheckoutViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Podfile contains:

```
 pod 'PureLayout'
 pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.6.8'
 pod 'Crashlytics'
 pod 'AFNetworking'
 pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.98.6'
 pod 'MBProgressHUD'
 pod 'SDWebImage'
 pod 'HCSStarRatingView'
 pod 'DateTools'
 pod 'SWTableViewCell'
 pod 'Stripe'
 pod 'CardIO'
 pod 'SAMTextView'
 pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.5'
```

I just typed `pod install` and launched the `.xcworkspace` it created.

I tried running this on Simulators but I can't get this to work. Can anyone help me?

I also tried the solution from this post:
[CocoaPods error with Card.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134679/cocoapods-error-with-card-io?answertab=active#tab-top).

But `$(inherited)` already exists in my **Other Linker Flags** section.

I am unable to figure out why it isn't working on my system. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this version

> pod 'CardIO', :git => 'https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK.git', :tag => '5.4.1'*

Add the following in a header file

```
#import <CardIO.h>
```

not forget adding "CardIO" in Other Linker Flags in Build Settings